# Scala return implicit in the context

Tags: scala, implicit

I wonder if it's possible to modify an implicit in a context with a function?

With a syntax like this

```
def modifyImplicit(implicit myImplicit: ImplicitType) : implicit ImplicitType {
        myImplicit.setSomthing(something)
        myImplicit
}
```

Because now I must return a type and after the function transform this in a new implicit 
if I need to use the function more than once it's became quickly painful.

Answer (score 2):

That's would introduce side-effect (automagically alter the environment without much notice), with it's not "very good".

Instead you can allow some operation to be executed within a managed context, in which you explicitly provide a replacement for the implicit.

```scala
implicit def TheDefaultTypeClass: ImplicitType

def withMyContext[T](f: (ImplicitType) => T): T = f(anotherTypeClass)
```

Then it can be used as following:

```scala
val s: String = withMyContext { i =>
  val x: ImplicitType = i // Dumb statement just to check type of `i`
  // some operations ...
  "OK" // result
}
```

Comment: You can also write `withMyContext { implicit i => ... }` to make `i` available as an implicit.

Comment: @AlexeyRomanov Right. Just don't mention it as it would then be the function passed to `withMyContext` that would override the implicit, not `withMyContext`, but that's definitely useful in some cases (e.g. loan pattern).

Answer (score 2):

No, it isn't possible. You could write

```
implicit def modifyImplicit(implicit myImplicit: ImplicitType): ImplicitType = ...
```

but this won't work the way you want (because for it to ever be called, an implicit of this type must already be available, so either the compiler won't continue looking for an implicit or it will and report conflicting implicits).

Also, having a *mutable* implicit value seems very likely to lead to bugs.

One possible workaround (in addition to the method proposed by applicius): extract your code into a method and call it with a modified implicit value.

```
def myMethod(args: ...)(implicit i: ImplicitType) = ...

myMethod(args)(modifyImplicit(implicitly[ImplicitType]))
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes I now but implicit are mutable because :
```

```
def modifyImplicit(implicit myImplicit: ImplicitType)  {
       implicit val myNewImplicit =  myImplicit.setSomthing(something)
       imASweetMethodWitchUseImplicit
       .... 
}
```

```

imASweetMethodWitchUseImplicit will use the last implicit setted in the context so we can't "stuck the imutability of the implicit"
I's actually the way i use to made what I whan but I thinks it's a little bit ugly.

I do that for "preparing" the context for other's function so I'm confident because it's just the variable whitch are hide not the call of my function ( witch modify the variables ) you know?

so Alexey I use the same option than you,but I take directly un implicit.
If I call more than one function it's become ugly

````
```
val result = modifyImplicit()
val result2 = modifyImplicit(result)
implicit val result3 = modifyImplicit(result2)
```
````

So maybe the solution of applicius can be more beautiful ?